# Difference between NSURLSession on iOS 8 and iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, basic-authentication

I have the following code to authenticate an iOS app to a MediaWiki server:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        task.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials]

        task.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                if data != nil {
                    let result = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    if resultIsValid(result) {
                        //Do authentication stuff
                    } else {
                        self.showLoginErrorMessage()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.showLoginErrorMessage()
                }
            })
            }.resume()
```

On iOS 8 this works perfect and I receive a HTTP 200 OK response. However, on iOS 9 I receive a 401 unauthorised. Unfortunately I do not have access to the server to see what it actually receives, and it is on an internal network, so I cannot link to the server. It uses HTTP basic access authentication, so I will assume that it should be the same as for any other server with that authentication type.

Is there any changes in the API from iOS 8 to 9 that could cause any issues like this? Could for instance other default headers like content type or user agent be changed/removed/added?

Edit:
After testing with requests.in I have discovered that by adding a Content-Type, this is a part of the header in iOS 8, but not in iOS 9. In iOS 8 I can still get the request through without setting the Content-Type, but it is still weird that it is not present in the iOS 9 request.

Comment: Could this be an issue [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW14)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, then I would never get the 401 unauthorised back. Plus, I added an exception to Info.plist to be sure.

Comment: It is the same on both versions. I also have an Android app that authenticates to the server without any problems. It is ONLY on iOS 9 that I experience the problem.

Comment: I've not noticed any difference apart from ATS. Buy can you set up a request bin url (http://requestb.in) then examine any differences the bin is receiving with iOS8 vs iOS9

Comment: Turns out the "Content-Type" is not present in iOS 9 when I send a request to requestb.in! Anyone else experiencing this? See edit above.

Comment: Why are you base 64 encoding the header value yourself rather than using NSURLCredential?

Comment: Adding the header is simpler than making a NSURLCredential, but as I discovered in the documentation, it is not possible to override the `Authentication` header anymore in iOS 9. Full explanation in my own answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out! Turns out that in iOS 9 the HTTPAdditionalHeaders property of NSURLSessionConfiguration is read-only, and any changes to it will not be reflected in the current NSURLSession. On top of that, the four headers `Authorisation`, `Connection`, `Host` and `WWW-Authenticate` cannot be modified. Therefore, the only way to do basic access authentication in iOS 9 is by using NSURLCredential as proposed by quellish.

For anyone having the same problem, here is the final code I used to have my authentication working for both iOS 8 and iOS 9:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://subdomain2.subdomain1.example.com")

let credential = NSURLCredential(user: username, password: password, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
let protectionSpace = NSURLProtectionSpace(host: url!.host!, port: 443, `protocol`: url!.scheme, realm: "subdomain2.example.com", authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic)
NSURLCredentialStorage.sharedCredentialStorage().setCredential(credential, forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

task.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    if data != nil {
         if responseIsValid(response) {
            //Do authenticated stuff
         } else {
             self.showLoginErrorMessage()
         }         
    } else {
         self.showLoginErrorMessage()
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: In the future, you might take a look at a tool such as http://www.charlesproxy.com to help decipher bi-directional web traffic.  It's nice b/c you can see both sides of the conversation, and it's much easier to set up for wireless sniffing than https://www.wireshark.org/